# Bison: Getting/Storing Values of nonterminals

Tags: grammar, bison, yacc, flex-lexer

I wrote a simple C-like grammar in Bison, and I have a weird problem.

In the following rule:

```
declaration:        "identifier" length init_values                      
                    {symbolTable.add($3,$4,$5);}
```

I want to get the int values of `length` and `init_values`, which are nonterminals, to store them in the symbol table. `identifier` is a token, and its literal value is stored correctly. However, I'm getting some integer values like 66236273 for the other symbols.

The nonterminal rules are:

```
length:             "number" {};                         
init_values:        "number" {};
```

I tried using tokens directly instead of nonterminals, but the parser couldn't differentiate between `number` and `length` and so on. It just parsed all integers as `number`, which made it crash.

Does anyone know how to get the actual values of these? i.e. the number values, which I was able to find in the last rules, but somehow they get lost when the parser goes a step back to the first rule.

Comment: Why are you using $3, $4, $5? There are only three symbols on the right hand side of that rule, so they should be. $1, $2, $3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more of your grammar and scanner definitions, it is hard to say for sure what you are doing wrong. But here are a few suggestions:

1. `{symbolTable.add($3,$4,$5);}` is incorrect with the provided grammar rule; it should be `{symbolTable.add($1,$2,$3);}` since right-hand-side values are counted from left to right starting with `$1`.
2. Assuming that `"identifier"` is a `char *` and `"integer"` is a `long` (or some such), it is important that all terminals and non-terminals be declared with the correct semantic value tag. See [the bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Multiple-Types).
3. There is no need for  `length: "number" {};`, but since the default action is effectively `$$ = $1`, it shouldn't do any harm as long as both `length` and `"number"` are declared with the correct type tag. I have no idea what you mean by "I tried using tokens directly instead of nonterminals" if it doesn't mean that you tried `declaration: "identifier" "number" "number"`; there is no reason why that shouldn't work (as long as the type declarations are correct).
4. If you are passing character strings in `yylval`, make sure you are copying the strings. `yylval.str = yytext;` is not correct, and will get you into trouble. See [this FAQ entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Strings-are-Destroyed).